# add extern cmake directory without building it

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project somewhere that I want to use in several other projects. Let's call it projA located at path `/projA`. I have built it in `/projA/build`. In this build folder there is some library `/projA/build/lib.a`.
Now if I want to create a new project B using project A in the folder `/projB` I know two options for the CMakeLists:

- Solution A

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
  project(projB)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} projB.cpp)
  add_subdirectory(/projA /projA/build)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} projA)
  ```

  The problem is that this solution will create new make files in `/projA/build` and the project A will be built again. Furthermore each time I will switch to a new project using projA, projA will be built again. So that's not a good solution. I would like to not overwrite all the build folder each time I switch between two project using projA.
- Solution B

  ```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
  project(projB)
  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} projB.cpp)
  link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /projA/build/lib.a)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /projA/include)
  # Include directories
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /projA/deps/depA/include)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE /projA/deps/depB/include)
  ...
  ```

  This solution works, but it's not very beautiful. I have to add a line for each include directory of all dependencies of project A.

So my question is: Is there a way to do it properly?

Comment: Both of your solutions don't work. You've already realized this for Solution A, but for Solution B simply consider what happens, if you execute the following sequence 1. configure projA 2. build projA 3. configure projB 4. clean projA 5. build projB. If you want to reuse the same project for multiple other projects add logic to this project to install it. Installations can be done to a user dir and cmake provides functionality to make it easily available via `find_package`. (I assume you don't want to build the target separately for each project?!)

Comment: Furthermore never ever hardcode absolute paths into your cmake project (unless you 100% know what you're doing). It's generally best to keep everything generated/built in the binary dir provided at the time of configuration; Using an absolute path for the location of the output file you won't even be able to set up different configurations of the same target on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build them entirely separately, you will need to go through the `find_package` infrastructure. Here's a complete example:

#### Project A

`lib.h`

```
#ifndef LIB_H
#define LIB_H

int lib();

#endif
```

`lib.c`

```
#include "lib.h"
int lib() { return 42; }
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(projA)

add_library(lib lib.c)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC "$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>")

# Export the target named lib for use in other projects
# from the build tree of this project.
export(TARGETS lib FILE projA-config.cmake)
```

#### Project B

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lib.h>

int main () {
    printf("%d\n", lib());
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(projB)

# Import the targets defined by projA
find_package(projA REQUIRED)

add_executable(projB main.c)
target_link_libraries(projB PRIVATE lib)
```

#### Compilation steps:

I'm imagining the two directories are next to each other, like so:

```
$ tree
.
├── projA
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── lib.c
│   └── lib.h
└── projB
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.c
```

Now we can build project A:

```
$ cmake -S projA -B projA/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/projA/build
$ cmake --build projA/build/ -- -v
[1/2] /usr/bin/cc  -I/path/to/projA -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lib.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lib.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lib.c.o -c /path/to/projA/lib.c
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f liblib.a && /usr/bin/ar qc liblib.a  CMakeFiles/lib.dir/lib.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib liblib.a && :
```

And now we'll build project B, and set the `projA_ROOT` variable to `/path/to/projA/build` so that `find_package(projA)` will succeed.

```
$ cmake -S projB -B projB/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DprojA_ROOT=$PWD/projA/build
...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /path/to/projB/build
$ cmake --build projB/build
$ cmake --build projB/build/ -- -v
[1/2] /usr/bin/cc  -isystem /path/to/projA -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/projB.dir/main.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/projB.dir/main.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/projB.dir/main.c.o -c /path/to/projB/main.c
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/cc -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/projB.dir/main.c.o -o projB  /path/to/projA/build/liblib.a && :
```

---

Clearly, this is non-obvious, and it's also sort of minimal. To build your own packages correctly, you should carefully read these CMake documentation pages:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/export.html

I would also suggest watching Craig Scott's talk "Deep CMake for Library Authors", here: https://youtu.be/m0DwB4OvDXk